# Retrive certains keys from an Object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code here.

```
const find = require('find-process');

find('name', 'TIDAL.exe')
  .then(function (list) {
    console.log(list)
  }, function (err) {
    console.log(err.stack || err);
});
```

which returns this here

```
[
  {
    pid: 7752,
    ppid: 9280,
    bin: '...',
    name: 'TIDAL.exe',
    cmd: '...'
  },
  {
    pid: 500,
    ppid: 7752,
    bin: '...',
    name: 'TIDAL.exe',
    cmd: '...'
  },
  {
    pid: 1100,
    ppid: 7752,
    bin: '...',
    name: 'TIDAL.exe',
    cmd: '...'
  },
  {
    pid: 6424,
    ppid: 7752,
    bin: '...',
    name: 'TIDAL.exe',
    cmd: '...'
  },
  {
    pid: 13692,
    ppid: 7752,
    bin: '...',
    name: 'TIDAL.exe',
    cmd: '...'
  },
  {
    pid: 3160,
    ppid: 7752,
    bin: '...',
    name: 'TIDAL.exe',
    cmd: '...'
  }
]
```

I need to extract the "pid" values and store them in an array but I'm stuck on how I should do it. I've looked around and tried some things out but I just can't get it to work.

Comment: What did you try? In ES6 you can use something like `let result = array.map(a => a.pid);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map function for getting the array of PID's

```js
var data = [{
    pid: 9280,
    bin: '...',
    name: 'TIDAL.exe',
    cmd: '...'
  },
  {
    pid: 500,
    ppid: 7752,
    bin: '...',
    name: 'TIDAL.exe',
    cmd: '...'
  },
  {
    pid: 1100,
    ppid: 7752,
    bin: '...',
    name: 'TIDAL.exe',
    cmd: '...'
  },
  {
    pid: 6424,
    ppid: 7752,
    bin: '...',
    name: 'TIDAL.exe',
    cmd: '...'
  },
  {
    pid: 13692,
    ppid: 7752,
    bin: '...',
    name: 'TIDAL.exe',
    cmd: '...'
  },
  {
    pid: 3160,
    ppid: 7752,
    bin: '...',
    name: 'TIDAL.exe',
    cmd: '...'
  }
];

let pids = data.map(item => item.pid);
console.log(pids);
```

It basically returns a new array with the filter that you've applied, Here I return `pid` of each item and map them into an array.

So your code should be

```
    const find = require('find-process');

    find('name', 'TIDAL.exe')
      .then(function (list) {
        let pids = list.map(item => item.pid);
        console.log(pids);
      }, function (err) {
        console.log(err.stack || err);
    });
```

Learn more on `Array.prototype.map()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: store the result of the map in array don't just log it.

Comment: Btw any important reason behind that?

Comment: yes keep make it a habit to write a clean code.

Comment: How would I convert it to an array at the start? It's outputting the data to the console but I need to convert the object into an array and then do the map thing.

Comment: Because if I try to do the map without converting to an array first it gives me this
[ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]

Comment: Not sure, if your data is like you've given in the question, it should have been fine? If it were an object, map would not run, so probably there's something else going on

Answer (score 2):

```js
let data=[{pid:9280,bin:"...",name:"TIDAL.exe",cmd:"..."},{pid:500,ppid:7752,bin:"...",name:"TIDAL.exe",cmd:"..."},{pid:1100,ppid:7752,bin:"...",name:"TIDAL.exe",cmd:"..."},{pid:6424,ppid:7752,bin:"...",name:"TIDAL.exe",cmd:"..."},{pid:13692,ppid:7752,bin:"...",name:"TIDAL.exe",cmd:"..."},{pid:3160,ppid:7752,bin:"...",name:"TIDAL.exe",cmd:"..."}];

let result = data.map(e => e.pid)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Adding a little bit of description would be helpful for the OP